# AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute '__version__' error while executing py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm very much new to Python and right now I'm trying to use Python for one of my automation tasks.

I'm trying to execute `Execute.py` while doing so I learned that my python setup should have modules `requests` (so downloaded 2.21.0),`urllib3` (so downloaded 1.21.1), `chardet`(so downloaded 3.0.4).

My Python version is 3.7.3

When I execute my `execute.py` I get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\python-3.7.3-embed-amd64\requests\__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    check_compatibility(urllib3.__version__, chardet.__version__)
AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute '__version__'
```

So just like we have in chardet folder, I have created a `version.py` under `urllib3` folder.

But still, I'm getting the same error.

Please, can someone help me with this? Which is taking my lot of time to find the resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You can uninstall and then install again all required package, by **pip uninstall**  and **pip install** .

you can also upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used (command require for this).

**pip install  --upgrade**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `pip` to install your libs, it will take care of the dependencies. It seems your urllib3 is not up to date...

Open a command prompt, and run:

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

Comment: this answer is not telling a new perspective. It tells about pip and upgrade!

Comment: What do you mean by "a new perspective"? At this time, I experienced the same problem and solved it this way, so I posted it to help others

Comment: dear olinox14, just attention to the question. It is about a programmer that is new to Python. when someone is new, s/he use ((pip install requests)) so upgrade the requests is irrelevant. The AAKANKSHA answer is more general for a new user.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is about probably where i might have gone wrong.(Nothing wrong in above two answers)

I had installed executable Python,in which i dint have PIP (though its 3.7 version)

so i was struggling to install PIP and all other modules(since im am new)

So ---I had used Web based installation (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/)

which had PIP and set the Python PATH on the go using which i upgraded required modules like others answered here.

Which has come handy to do the rest of the job ,where i dint come across any issues while executing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the requests. It was for A circular dependency occurs when two or more modules depend on each other. This is for the fact that each module is defined in terms of the other.

Please try to rename your file. The error for this error is usually due to a conflict with the file name where you are trying to import the requests module.

I was also having same problem, where my file name was token.py and I was trying to import the requests module. I changed the file name and it worked.